# tricky mysql query counting records in several categories

Tags: php, mysql

here's my data structure:
there are items and each item may have up to 3 categories

```
categories
id   name
-----------------------
1    cat1
2    cat2
3    cat3

items
id  name     category1  category2  category3
-----------------------------------------------
1   item1    1          2          3
2   item2    1          2       
3   item3    2          1          3
4   item4    2          3        
5   item5    3          1          2
```

desired output:

```
cat   cat_name   total_items
-----------------------------------------------
1     cat1       4
2     cat2       5
3     cat3       4
```

the only way i could achieve it was by defining a view for items using `CONCAT_WS` which will convert all 3 categories into a delimited string, then query it using `FIND_IN_SET` but i think there should be a better/faster way. any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Can you change your table design?

Comment: funny that you asked .. unfortunately not :( i didn't design it and it's already a live system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a select subquery to count the items that are in the category by using where category1, category2 or category3.

```
SELECT c.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM items i WHERE i.category1 = c.id OR i.category2 = c.id OR i.category3 = c.id) as total_items 
    FROM categories c
```